# Workflow for finding words in a text that are not in GSL or AWL

Tags: discussion

As an English teacher, I want to be able to quickly identify words in a given text that are NOT on the General Service List (GSL) or the Academic Word List (AWL). This will help me understand which words my students might have trouble with. What are some efficient options for doing this?

Comment: This question and your answer would probably work better on [ell.se]

Comment: Almost any program that accepts a list of "stop words" (i.e, words that should be ignored) would pick out only the words not on any list supplied them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can you suggest a program that uses stop words? That would also be very useful for me

Answer (score 2):

I found a tool that does this well: [EAP Foundation Vocabulary profiler](https://www.eapfoundation.com/vocab/profiler/).

Comment: Wow...that site is great.